# MySQL query calculate Previous Month

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate total amount in previous month.

```
$people_sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS people"
    . " FROM room WHERE userid = '$userid'"
    . " AND date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')"
    .          " AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')";
```

For example 1st June - 30th 2013

I get 0 by running the above query.

How to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I run query

```
SELECT 
  SUM(amount) AS people, 
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') as from_date, 
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as to_date
FROM room 
WHERE userid = 1
  AND date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') 
  AND date < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

I got good values.

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE room 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     userid int,
     date datetime,
     amount integer
    );

INSERT INTO room
(userid, date, amount)
VALUES
(1, now(), 1), (1, now(), 2), (1, '2010-01-01', 4), (1, '2013-06-20', 8)
```

Comment: and for quicker response time I suggest using Gordon Linoff  second way.

Comment: Superb! You make me smile. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert the strings back to dates:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS people
FROM room
WHERE userid = '$userid' AND
      date >= date(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')) AND
      date < date(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'))
```

This uses the `date()` function  You can also use `str_to_date()` to provide specific formats.

I changed the `between` because it would include the first day of the current month.

An alternative way of formulating this is:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS people
FROM room
WHERE userid = '$userid' AND
      date_format(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now() - interval 1 month, '%Y-%m')
```

This is more concise.  Your method has the advantage that it can make use of an index on `date`.